# Android :Open source project

Tags: android, open-source

I am working on android app and I want to open source. How can i do that ?? what would be the best place to that ?

a friend suggest google code , svn and eclipse off course of android. If so can some one one to site which gives a good introduction or walk through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like [GitHub](http://github.com/).  Git is a powerful tool for version control, and GitHub is pretty gentle with you when you're just starting out.  It's also really easy borrow other people's code and look at what they've done.

To learn git and GitHub, here's a [little tutorial](http://b.lesseverything.com/2008/3/25/got-git-howto-git-and-github) that I like.  The only problem is that git is difficult to use on Windows, but it is possible.  Linux is a better development environment anyway.

If you must use Windows, go for something else like SourceForge or Google Code.  Google Code is probably better because it uses both Mercurial and Subversion.  I would go with Mercurial over Subversion any day because it's similar to git, which means it's leagues above everything else in terms of flexibility and features.

Note:

Don't bother with svn if you can use git or mercurial instead, you'll be much happier you did.  Everything svn (Subversion) can do, git can do, but not vise versa (like branching and forking).  Also, avoid the GPL, it will only bring you pain.  Start with a permissive license like MIT or BSD unless you need the restrictions of the GPL or LGPL.

Comment: git on windows is no harder than on linux. msysgit is a very good port.